# get data in angular stored as array of objects

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I want to get data stored in template_A that is col_1 and col_2 and print in table format, but i am getting [object,object]. I don't know how to get data stored as array of object.

**I want to print next to template_A. You can have a look at array in console.**

[image]

[image]

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "611f354944c4571778df456c"
    },
    "assignmentId": "61235a452a8a2428a43514ed",
    "studentId": "60dafc5c0254f7122e9fe7f0",
    "assignmentOf": "subject",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-08-20T04:53:29.717Z"
    },
    "updateAt": {
        "$date": "2021-08-20T04:53:29.717Z"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "grade": "b ",
    "remark": "good",
    "template": "template_A",
    "template_A": {
        "col_1": "col_1",
        "col_2": "col_2"
    },
    "template_B": {
        "col_1": "col_1",
        "col_2": "col_2"
    }
}
```

Angular app

```
                          <table>
                            <tr >
                              <td>{{ singleAssignment.template }}</td>
                              <td>{{ singleAssignment.template_A[0] }}</td>
                              <!-- <td>{{ singleAssignment.template_A[0] }}</td> -->
                            </tr>
                          </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have modified code for you please have a look

**TS CODE**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  singleAssignment: any;

  constructor() {
    this.singleAssignment = {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "611f354944c4571778df456c"
      },
      "assignmentId": "61235a452a8a2428a43514ed",
      "studentId": "60dafc5c0254f7122e9fe7f0",
      "assignmentOf": "subject",
      "createdAt": {
          "$date": "2021-08-20T04:53:29.717Z"
      },
      "updateAt": {
          "$date": "2021-08-20T04:53:29.717Z"
      },
      "__v": 0,
      "grade": "b ",
      "remark": "good",
      "template": "template_A",
      "template_A": {
          "col_1": "col_1",
          "col_2": "col_2"
      },
      "template_B": {
          "col_1": "col_1",
          "col_2": "col_2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr >
      <td>{{ singleAssignment.template }}</td>
      <td>{{ singleAssignment.template_A['col_1']}}</td>
      <td>{{ singleAssignment.template_A['col_2'] }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

============================================================================

**UPDATED**

**TS CODE**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  singleAssignment: any;

  constructor() {
    this.singleAssignment = {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "611f354944c4571778df456c"
      },
      "assignmentId": "61235a452a8a2428a43514ed",
      "studentId": "60dafc5c0254f7122e9fe7f0",
      "assignmentOf": "subject",
      "createdAt": {
          "$date": "2021-08-20T04:53:29.717Z"
      },
      "updateAt": {
          "$date": "2021-08-20T04:53:29.717Z"
      },
      "__v": 0,
      "grade": "b ",
      "remark": "good",
      "template": "template_A",
      "template_A": [
        {
          "col_1": "col_1",
          "col_2": "col_2"
        }
      ],
      "template_B": {
          "col_1": "col_1",
          "col_2": "col_2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr >
      <td>{{ singleAssignment.template }}</td>
      <td>{{ singleAssignment.template_A[0]['col_1']}}</td>
      <td>{{ singleAssignment.template_A[0]['col_2'] }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: @Suneelumar i tried your solution din't work for me.

Comment: can you please share your code? so that I can check

Comment: Like I also shared screenshot by running this above example, for me it's working fine, what issue you are facing?

Comment: `                            <table>
                            <tr >
                              <td>{{ singleAssignment.template }}</td>
                              <td>{{ singleAssignment.template_A['col_1'] }}</td>
                              <td>{{ singleAssignment.template_A['col_2'] }}</td>
                              </tr>
                          </table>`     used this solution i am not getting any result. i can fetch template but not template_A

Comment: share your output screenshot and also code this `singleAssignment`

Comment: I am new to stack overflow How t add screenshot?  on a comment

Comment: Ques updated! with images of code and singleassignment data in console.

Comment: I checked your screenshot and also the console log, it seems `template_A` is an `array` not an `object`, As in your question you mention that the `template_A` is an `object`, well leave it, I am going to update my answer will let you know once done

Comment: I Update the Answer please have a look

Comment: What if i only want t print the table if template column is not empty?

Comment: Just apply `*ngIf` condition with `<table>` tag like this `<table *ngIf="singleAssignment.template">`

Answer (score 2):

Two ways

**1.** Transform your json object to json array, and then use *ngFor in html.

```
"template_A": [
        { "col_1": "col_1" },
        { "col_2": "col_2" },
      ]
```

**2.** use Object.keys in *ngFor

```
"template_A": {
      "col_1": "col_1_value",
      "col_2": "col_2_value"
  }
```

in .ts file

```
public ObjectKeys = Object.keys
```

in .html file

```
<div  *ngFor="let cols of ObjectKeys(singleAssignment.template_A)">
   {{cols}}
   {{singleAssignment.template_A[cols]}}
</div>
```

output -

```
col_1 col_1_value
col_2 col_2_value
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `*ngFor` directive on `singleAssignment.template_A` and then iterate its items.

Comment: @Amna.Naveed how are you suggesting t implement it in table fomat? Can you give example.